# on installation of gitlab , at final step sudo service gitlab start ,facing an issue i.e. unicorn webserver is not running ,what to do?

Tags: ruby, gitlab

On installing gitlab, everything is fine.
But at final step of installation when I run command

```
$ sudo service gitlab start
```

it shows an error i.e., unicorn web server is not working but GitLab Sidekiq job dispatcher with pid 4182 is running properly.

Comment: what the error message is?

Comment: Please tag this post in [gitlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitlab) .

Comment: We have an exception on SO that allows tool questions when the tools are used primarily by programmers, but questions about how to get GitLab running seem right on the edge of what should be in scope on SO.  I'm voting to leave open, since I'm not positive this should be out of scope.

Comment: @Aleksey  on running this command it shows :    [!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting end-of-input - "mysql2","0.2.7" 
         ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /home/git/gitlab/Gemfile:208
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  end
 >  "mysql2","0.2.7" 
 #  -------------------------------------------

GitLab is not running.